# Are there any potential risks of avoiding type 3 fonts when using matplotlib to draw figures

Tags: latex

Many conferences/journals start asking me to use Type 1 font in the submitted PDF. So when I use matplotlib to generate figures, I have two choices:

- Configure matplotlib to only use tex fonts

```
rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

- Use matplotlib default font but generate png to insert

The problem with option 1 is the tex font looks not as good as matplotlib's default font. The problem with option 2 is it generates non-zoomable png files and may become blurring when I resize the figure.

May I know if you have any experience with the potential risks of the two options, and which one will you choose when creating figures for papers?

Comment: This is quite possibly off-topic for this site. I will, however, make one comment. Why use PNG? You should be able to save the Matplotlib figures as EPS files, which will not result in blurring.

Comment: The reason I asked it here is that I was thinking this is a more publication-related question. But you are right. Maybe I should consider moving it to latex stack exchange. And thanks for the suggestion!